# How to store Paint objects?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, drawing

I have many (about 40) instances of my class which is a custom view. All these instances use the same Paint objects to draw. Is there better method than making them static members of class to save memory used by application?

Comment: Why are they using the same paint object? Does it have some functionality that is used by multiple classes? Does the Paint object represent something concrete? if not, a static class might indeed suit you better. If you refactor it into a static class, a name such as Painter might work better than Paint

Comment: These classes are calendar's cells and uses the same Paints to draw rect, text, etc.